# How should I model a database structure to store information about words?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have an application where the *user* can click on any *word* in a *text*, which will bring back related information about the *base word* and the specific *inflection* (*word form*) of the *word* clicked. I've tried representing this in a multitude of ways, but now that I'm close to launch, I'm worried as hell about the best way to represent it (this is my first ever project with programming, so I have no idea what I'm in for).

#### Considerations

The way I had originally set this up was that there was a `base word` table that contained the `base word`, `part of speech`, and then an array of `word forms` for each base word.

I then learned that this was a bad idea in terms of normalization, and I also realized that I needed to store specific `inflection` information for the words (`mood`, `tense`, `person`, etc.), so I rearranged it.

In the second iteration, I had three tables, a `base_word` table that had the `base_word` and the `part of speech`, a `word` table that had the `word` and its `inflection` information, and then a “join” table between them that contained the `base_word_id` and the `word_id`.

However, I've been re-thinking this setup, because semantically speaking, a *base word* is also a *word*, just a *specific type of word*. So in this case, I feel like a “self-join” table might be most appropriate, although I could be completely overthinking this. In the “self-join” table, there would be an `is_baseword` boolean attribute, which would theoretically allow all the `inflection` columns to store NULL marks if it was set to *true*. Is this a better idea?

---

**Note**: I found these two similar questions which didn't seem to completely answer my questions, so I'm posting my twist on these here:

- [Table design for a dictionary that can have words with many different spellings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121681/table-design-for-a-dictionary-that-can-have-words-with-many-different-spellings)
- [How can I represent a list of words and related words in a relational structure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139734/how-can-i-represent-a-list-of-words-and-related-words-in-a-relational-structure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your design for a one to many join with `base_word` in one table and word forms in another is fine. The reasons I make this judgement are:

1. The `base_word`, as an entity, is sufficiently different to `word_forms` as to represent a different entity. For instance, if you were to include the words origin language, this would also be only applicable to the base word entity, not its word forms.
2. Storing the data in the same table will have implications on the size of the tables due to having sparse columns with attributes that are associated with `base_word` OR `word_form` only, meaning they are NULL or empty for the others. You point this out with the `is_baseword` and `inflection` columns. Having a bunch of NULL values on a row which will never be changed is usually a reason to use the [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model or split into different entities.
3. Performance considerations for queries should be taken into account. With the additional size consideration a self join to a sparsely populated table will likely not be as performant. You will probably find yourself indexing a single table for `base_words` OR `word_forms` separately. The indexes will be larger and more difficult to maintain for inserts/deletes etc. Better to have indexes on smaller tables and to have as few as possible on a table.

Don't get too concerned with perfect normalization. While a perfectly normalized system may adhere to strict information science principles, it is often better in the real world to have a slightly denormalized database for other reasons.

Comment: Good calls - I'm still getting the hang of understanding things about database sizes. Thanks!

Comment: Think about the size like an Excel spreadsheet where the used area is the size. For every column you add the size increases by the column size squared (height x width in Excel, extra column size x num rows in a DB), regardless of if that column has a value or not. This is not true of some declared column sizes, but is true of the most common column types. The database system generally doesn't care if the space is empty it will allocate some space to where a value COULD be in order to avoid future page splits if you were to change the value from NULL to a value.